# Как удалить елемент после послденего вызова метода next()

Tags: java, очередь, итераторы

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с методом remove() используя iterator.
У меня почему-то не удаляется последнее вхождение после метода next().

Код прилагаю ниже + в методе test7() указан какой должен быть вывод

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class QueueImpl implements Queue {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    int current = 0;

    @Override
    public void enqueue(Object element) {
        Node a = new Node();
        a.element = element;

        if (tail == null) {
            head = a;
            tail = a;
        } else {
            tail.next = a;
            tail = a;
        }
        current++;
    }

    @Override
    public Object dequeue() {
        Node element = head;
        head = element.next;
        current--;
        return element.element;
    }

    @Override
    public Object top() {
        return head.element;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        current = 0;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return current;
    }

    class Node {
        Object element;
        Node next;
        Node prev;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    public class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {

        Node iteratorImpl = head;
        Node follow;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iteratorImpl != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            follow = iteratorImpl;
            iteratorImpl = iteratorImpl.next;
            return follow.element;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            Node current = head;

            while (current != follow) {
                if (current.next == tail) {
                    tail = current;
                    break;
                } else {
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.next == null) {
                stringBuilder.append(current.element);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(current.element).append(" ");
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

        return "[" + stringBuilder.toString() + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test7();
    }

    public static void test7() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");

        Iterator it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        /* an output must be as the following:
        *************************************
        A
        B
        C
        [A, B]
        A
        [B]
        B
        []
        *************************************
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список двухсвязанный, но ссылка на предыдущий элемент не заполняется.

```
@Override
public void enqueue(Object element) 
{
    Node a = new Node();
    a.element = element;

    if (tail == null) {
        head = a;
        tail = a;
    } else {
        tail.next = a;
        a.prev = tail; // Заполняем
        tail = a;
    }
    current++;
}
```

И, как следствие, корректный метод удаления:

```
@Override
public void remove()
{
    Node prev = follow.prev;
    Node next = follow.next;

    if (prev != null)
        prev.next = follow.next;

    if (next != null)
        next.prev = follow.prev;

    if (follow == head)
        head = next;
}
```